# Turning File Vault on, and instantly upgrading to macOS Big Sur is not a problem?

Tags: macos, filevault

I just got a new MacBook Pro 16 inch from the IT department, and after I turned on the machine, it asked me for a series of set up questions.

One of them is File Vault, so I answered "Yes".  But it takes no time to set it up, as opposed to some online page stating [it took forever](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8455024).

But there is another post stating it will be [encrypting silently in the background](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837)?

So while I am not sure if it really should take some time or is it instant, due to my work, I need to immediately upgrade to macOS Big Sur from Catalina.

So will it be alright while File Vault is encrypting files in the background and the OS is being upgraded?  I take it the upgrade process should be smart enough to handle that.

Comment: Gotta ask, if this machine belongs to where you work, why are you upgrading the OS on it?  As for whether it's done, use 'diskutil cs list' at a shell prompt.

Comment: that's because the department asked me to upgrade to the latest macOS, possibly they want all the most updated security patches for the latest OS, I think. Also, for the software build process, it may also be best if everybody is using the same OS, instead of somebody using Catalina, somebody using Mojave

Comment: You can check whether it's finished encrypting in the File Vault settings (Privacy panel in System Preferences). If it doesn't indicate it's still encrypting, I'd restart the computer first to be sure then go ahead with the update.

Comment: @nonopolarity Which is, of course, a nonsense statement.  Catalina is receiving security patches and will do so for another year (at least).

Comment: @MarcWilson even though it is receiving security patch, our software development team cannot afford to have everybody running different OS versions, and different versions of Ruby, Node.js, npm, etc. It'd be a mess to debug into our build process if any issue happens, so what is common in software companies is that we require everybody doing development work use the same OS version, same Ruby, same Node.js and npm... to minimize the number of possible issues

Comment: @nonopolarity How did it go?  Were you able to upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

I manage macbook pros all day everyday, and I absolutely do not recommend upgrading OS's in the middle of encryption.

That said, since it's a new machine with no files on it, and since you enabled it already, chances are that by the time I post this, the encryption process is complete (only if it has been connected to power! otherwise the encryption pauses until it IS connected to a power source).

Comment: it is a new machine with no file on it, but just the OS part is a lot of files... also, I wonder if File Vault knows to stop when the power cord is not plugged in, then maybe when the OS upgrade starts, it also can set a flag which File Vault will know to not proceed with encryption for the moment

Comment: While digging around I found some additional info... you might not actually even be able to upgrade the OS mid-encryption. Even if it's paused.   If you attempt it, you would run into this message:  "you may not install to this volume because it is currently being encrypted"

Answer (score 2):

If it has a T2 chip it's encrypted already with blank password. Turning FileVault on just sets a different password and is instant.

From this Apple PDF : [Apple T2 Security Chip
Security Overview](https://www.apple.com/ca/mac/docs/Apple_T2_Security_Chip_Overview.pdf)

> If FileVault isn’t enabled on a Mac with the T2 chip during the initial Setup
> Assistant process, the volume is still encrypted, but the volume key is protected
> only by the hardware UID in the Secure Enclave. If FileVault is enabled later—a
> process that is immediate since the data was already encrypted—an anti-replay
> mechanism prevents the old key (based on hardware UID only) from being used
> to decrypt the volume. The volume is then protected by a combination of the
> user password with the hardware UID as previously described.

The links in the question apply to older models.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in the middle of upgrading an early 2014 MacBook Air, lowest spec (4GB, 128GB SSD) from Catalina to Big Sur which has File Vault enabled. After freeing up enough space to do the upgrade, I continue to get “not enough space free” messages. In the middle of turning off “Vile Fault” to see if this lets me continue.
[image: Big Sur Installer Error Message]

[Finder Free Space][image: ][1]]

Comment: Decryption estimates cycling between over an hour to ~30 minutes.